# How to implement Ouath2 for Osticket?

Tags: oauth-2.0, osticket

ive been trying to implement oauth2 for osticket hosted on my apache2 server. After following the docs sucessfully [official osticket documentation for oauth2 plugin](https://docs.osticket.com/en/latest/OAuth2/Microsoft%20Authentication%20(SSO)%20Guide.html)

ive been stuck at a point where, the app is unable to redirect to the /api/oauth endpoint after user authentication with the IdP and server refuses to identify any such url.
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GU8Ro.png)
Since no documentation was provided for the backend implemetation for the Oauth2 client plugin i assumed it would be automatically taken care of. What steps should i proceed with?
Heres what my apache config file for Osticket looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName abc.com
        DocumentRoot /www/itsm

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
        RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/itsm_error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/itsm_access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName abc.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/osTicket/upload


        <Directory /www/itsm/>
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
        #RewriteEngine On
        #RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
        #RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/itsm_error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/itsm_access.log combined
    
    SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/abc.com/cert.pem
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/abc.com/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/abc.com/privkey.pem


        <Directory "/var/www/osTicket/upload">
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Restricted Content"
        AuthUserFile /var/www/osTicket/upload/.htpasswd
        Require valid-user
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working on osticket 1.17.3 vanilla - download from the [ost webpage](https://osticket.com/download/) with oauth2/azure:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

 <VirtualHost *:443>
   DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/"
   ServerName support.somewhereelse.ch
   ServerAdmin it@support.somewhereelse.ch

  ErrorLog    /dev/stdout
  TransferLog /dev/stdout
  CustomLog   /dev/stdout combined

  RewriteEngine On

   <Directory "/var/www/html">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride All
   </Directory>

   SSLEngine on

   SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/pem
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/key

 </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>



<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName support.somewhereelse.ch
    redirect permanent / https://support.somewhereelse.ch/
</VirtualHost>
```